# Define a property in sub class, then use it in parent class, strange behavour in PHP?

Tags: java, c#, php, c++, oop

In PHP, I define a property named $table_name in the sub class, then in the parent class, I can use this property:

```
class A{
public function getTable(){
    return $this->table_name;
}
}

class B extends A{

protected $table_name='admin;

}
```

Could this be possible in Java or C++? I just wonder if this is a good OOP practice, or it is just doable in PHP as PHP is an interpreting language.

Update: I didn't realized this is possible in PHP until I found a MVC framework uses it!When I was learning Java, I didn't remember anything like this, so I thought it might worth discussing.

Comment: This is news to me ... This certainly wouldn't work in C# but not sure about Java etc (I'd guess not).

Comment: Add tags for other languages so more peolpe can see your question.

Comment: Due to scoping, this wouldn't work in most languages. IMO it is not good OOP practice due to having circular dependency between a parent and child instead of one way dependency.

Comment: Doesn't work in C++. You have to have `table_name` declared in the base-class (`A` in this case). I'm pretty sure that applies to ALL of the other languages mentioned.

Comment: The fact that you can do it doesn't mean you should. I didn't know that PHP would allow this as I never would have thought of trying! I expect it can be considered as undocumented behaviour and as such, should not be relied upon as the result is undefined and may change in the future. I'd be interested to know which framework you found this in so I can avoid it in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main points of OOP is polymorphism and the ability to used derived classes. The idea behind this is that you can have access to base properties (in a base class) and rely on them being there in any derived class.

Doing what has been demonstrated above breaks that. It essentially means that base class is useless for anything other than it's derived class and this behaviour should be avoided.

So: You access base properties from derived classes, not the other way around.

Short version: This is bad OOP practice.

Comment: Yes, and as all the comments above, this is BAD OOP practice, and this is the drawback of PHP's OOP --- it allows many ways for writing poor OOP code!

Comment: I completely agree agree. (I've updated my post with those exact words as it hits the nail on the head - except the PHP part, I don't want to start a flame war ;) )

Comment: @user305611156 The fact that PHP allows this particular bad practice doesn't make PHP a bad language. There are many examples of bad practice that shouldn't be used in many languages, it doesn't make them bad. I agree that this particular example is surprising, but it is an example of mis-use and doesn't make the whole language bad as a result.

Comment: @vascowhite, I agree, it is just that PHP allows such behavior, while other strong-type languages do not. A good programmer never code that way, but I did see some PHP code like this.

Comment: @webnoob,thanks for the reply. I accepted the answer as I guess you might want me to accept it :)